# Var++ causes RangeError in recursive function parameter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have a simple linear recursive function in JavaScript computing a factorial of a number.

```
function factorialImproved(n) {

  function factorialIter(p, c, m) {
    if (c > m) {
      return p;
    } else {
      return factorialIter(c * p, c++, m); // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded // ++c or c+1 is OK
    }
  }

  return (factorialIter(1, 1, n))
}
```

I'm trying to figure out why I get RangeError with `c++` but not with `++c` or `c+1`.

Comment: C++ take the C value and then increase this. ++C first increase the C value and then take this

Comment: @DavidUntama [C++ take the C value and then adds classes and templates](http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/linuxjournal/articles/070/7099/7099f1.jpg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`(c++)` evaluates as `c`. So you are calling `factorialIter` with the same `c` every time.

Therefore, `c = 1` won't be bigger than `m = n` unless `n < 1`.

However, `(++c)` evaluates as `c+1`. Just remember this rule:

- `(++c)`: first increment then `c`.
- `(c++)`: first `c` then increment.

In my opinion, you should be using `c+1`. Do not use `c++` or `++c` unless you want to use `c` in that scope later.

Answer (score 1):

You return the same value of `c`, because with [postfix increment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators), it returns the actual value and then it increments the variable.

For getting a result, you could use just `c + 1` as value. Or use prefix increment. But if you do not use the variable again, it is not advisable.

```js
function factorialImproved(n) {

    function factorialIter(p, c, m) {
        if (c > m) {
            return p;
        } else {
            return factorialIter(c * p, c + 1, m); // RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded // ++c or c+1 is OK
        }
    }

    return (factorialIter(1, 1, n))
}

console.log(factorialImproved(5));
```